# Remove Sample Code references in Managed package metadata

Tags: managed-package, security-review

One of our partners reached out to us in helping their package pass security review. The recent report they received contains the following issue:

1. Sample Code in Production
2. Account.object

Issue Description:

> There's a lot of great sample code available to developers all over
>   the internet. While useful in learning best practices or new
>   technologies, sample or documentation code should not be directly
>   included in production packages. This can lead to propagation of
>   vulnerabilities or software weaknesses, whether intentional or not on
>   the part of the sample/documentation code author, throughout many
>   packages.
>
> Sample code should always be used as an educational tool in
>   preparation for developing your own application. When you are building
>   out your production code you should always write the code yourself and
>   avoid copying/pasting code from other sources that you do not directly
>   control.
>
> For Salesforce developers, a common red flag for copying sample code
>   is the inclusion of an Account.object file with a  parameter of
>   'http://www.genwatt.com/genwatt/billing.htm?actname={!Account_Name}.
>   This code comes from Salesforce-provided sample and documentation
>   code. Fortunately, in this case this is sample Salesforce code and
>   that URL is not active.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <webLinks>
        <fullName>Billing</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>link</displayType>
        <encodingKey>UTF-8</encodingKey>
        <hasMenubar>true</hasMenubar>
        <hasScrollbars>true</hasScrollbars>
        <hasToolbar>true</hasToolbar>
        <height>600</height>
        <isResizable>true</isResizable>
        <linkType>url</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Billing(Not Using)</masterLabel>
        <openType>newWindow</openType>
        <position>none</position>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <showsLocation>true</showsLocation>
        <showsStatus>true</showsStatus>
        <url>http://www.genwatt.com/genwatt/billing.htm</url>
    </webLinks>
</CustomObject>
```

We could understand the package references the codes which salesforce sample which ideally used for learning purpose.

My question is there's a way to quickly find possible demo code references in the packages quickly without going through all the metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a managed package uploaded... oops. You're going to have a hard time undoing the situation. You should attempt to [rollback all versions back to beta first](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000272242&language=en_US&type=1). To figure out what's sample metadata, create a new developer edition, pull both orgs down in to an IDE, and perform a DIFF to spot the differences.

Anything that's different should be part of your package, anything that's *not* different is standard template metadata and needs to be removed. There's no easy automated way to do this, but there's also not a lot of data to go through. Last I checked, I believe the only customizations are for Cases, Accounts, and Opportunities.

Alternatively, if you still have trouble, create a new Scratch Org. These always come as a "clean slate", so you should be able to diff between a new Developer Edition and a Scratch Org. Anything that shows up in the diff is template metadata. That should help you easily identify which customizations need to be removed.

Comment: Any reason why we need to compare new Dev org and a Scratch org?

Comment: @Praveen Because Salesforce doesn't have a comprehensive documentation that outlines all customization. We're left to figure out what's new and what's not.